# In ASP.NET 3.5, what is the namespace for the ReorderList control?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am trying to extend the `Reorderlist` contorl in ASP.Net 3.5, however I cannot find which namespace I need to import in order to inherit form the original control (System.Web.UI.WebControls does not appear to be it).

In ASP 2, I know it came as part of the AjaxToolKit, but I am specifically looking for the version rolled into 3.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running .NET 3.5 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1? If not, then upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the asp.net AJAX framework was rolled into 3.5, the control toolkit was not. You'll still need to download / add a reference to the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit if you want to use the Reorderlist control.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be in the AjaxControlKit namespace (it was in asp2 at least)